# get name of submit button

Tags: jsp, servlets

I've got such form

```
<form action="xmlServletPath" method="POST" id="c1">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <input type="submit" name="task1" value="Генерация таблиц по переданным  параметрам: заголовок, количество строк и столбцов, цвет фона." />
        </li>

        <li>
        <input type="submit" name="task2" value="Вычисление тригонометрических функций в градусах и радианах с указанной точностью. Выбор функций должен осуществляться через выпадающий список." />
        </li>

        <li>
        <input type="submit" name="task3" value="Выбор  изображения  по  тематике  (природа,  автомобили,  дети  и  т.д.)  и его отображение."/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I want to get the name of pressed button - for example if I pressed button with name `task1` I want to get this name in servlet.
But how?

`getParameter` allows to check whether button with `getParameter` name was pressed. 
I need something like this -

```
 String req = request.getAttributeName('name'); // req contains task1(or task2, task3)
```

and in the `req` there will be `task1` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `<button>` tag instead ([Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp))

```
<form action="xmlServletPath" method="POST" id="c1">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button type="submit" name="mybutton" value="task1">
                Генерация таблиц по переданным  параметрам: заголовок, количество строк и столбцов, цвет фона.
            </button>
        </li>

        <li>
            <button type="submit" name="mybutton" value="task2">
                Вычисление тригонометрических функций в градусах и радианах с указанной точностью. Выбор функций должен осуществляться через выпадающий список.
            </button>
        </li>

        <li>
            <button type="submit" name="mybutton" value="task3">
                Выбор  изображения  по  тематике  (природа,  автомобили,  дети  и  т.д.)  и его отображение.
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

In your servlet:

```
String req = request.getAttributeName('mybutton');
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use three forms and hidden fields:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <form action="xmlServletPath" method="POST" id="c1">
            <input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="task1" />
            <input type="submit" name="task1" value="Генерация таблиц по переданным  параметрам: заголовок, количество строк и столбцов, цвет фона." />
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="xmlServletPath" method="POST" id="c2">
            <input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="task2" />
            <input type="submit" name="task2" value="Вычисление тригонометрических функций в градусах и радианах с указанной точностью. Выбор функций должен осуществляться через выпадающий список." />
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="xmlServletPath" method="POST" id="c3">
            <input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="task3" />
            <input type="submit" name="task3" value="Выбор  изображения  по  тематике  (природа,  автомобили,  дети  и  т.д.)  и его отображение."/>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously when you have 3 submit buttons on one form only 1 can be pressed, so just check all 3:

```
 String submitBtn01_Value = request.getParameter("task1");
 String submitBtn02_Value = request.getParameter("task2");
 String submitBtn03_Value = request.getParameter("task3");
```

Whichever one is not null is the one that was pressed.

But it makes more sense to me to just name all your submit buttons the same thing ('submit' for example) and do your switching by the value. (But mine are never as long as yours.)

```
 String submitBtnValue = request.getParameter("submit");
 if("first task name".equals(submitBtnValue))
 {
  ...
 }
 else if("second task name".equals(submitBtnValue))
 .....
```